# Running script on another server and append value to the same file

Tags: bash, shell, public-key-encryption

This is a script I developed to check memory on a server and return values in a table which can be mailed to me. I've created Public Key authentication from the server of the script to the disk check.

```
mem_check Variable User Server
{
ssh $3@$2 a1=$1 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'
echo $a1 >> table
echo $HOSTNAME >> table
echo ${HOME//home/} | tr -d / | sed ':a;N;s/\n/ /g' >> table
mem=$(df -kh /tmp | grep -vE '^Filesystem|cdrom' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d '%' -f 1 )
if [ $mem -ge 80 ]; then
echo -e "$mem% \n<font style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FF0000\">R</font>\n" >> table
else
echo -e "$mem% \n<font style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #33cc33\">G</font>\n" >> table
fi
ENDSSH
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that it is creating the table file in the remote server only and not in the directory where the shell is running?
Is it possible to append the file in the same directory?

If not should I copy the table back to the host server and than append it myself?
Also if that is the case how do I delete the lagging copies of the table files remaining in that server?

EDIT: I'm able to append the file to the same server by using scp... I am wondering if there is a way to do directly?

```
scp $3@$2:/home/$3/table2 /home/host/table2
cat table2 >> table
```

Comment: You are asking ssh to exist your whole script in the remote directory so everything is normal. You wanna get your `table` file only in your current directory where the script is running ?

Comment: I want the table file in my current directory. Currently it is creating the file in the remote server while the script is running.

Comment: in your script (running on remote server)use ssh and echo output lines in local directly file. (ssh user@localserver "echo $output >> localfile" )

Comment: So you're referring the $output as the remote file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should retrieve the data on your remote server and then process the data on your computer. Here is one of the solution :

```
mem_check Variable User Server
{
    mem=`ssh $3@$2 "df -h /tmp --output=pcent | grep -v Use | cut -d '%' -f 1"`
    echo $1 >> table
    echo $2 >> table
    echo $3 >> table
    if [ $mem -ge 80 ]; then
        echo -e "$mem% \n<font style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FF0000\">R</font>\n" >> table
    else
        echo -e "$mem% \n<font style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #33cc33\">G</font>\n" >> table
    fi
}
```

I have changed command to retrieve space because `df` has a built-in fonction to format output so you don't need to `awk`. Also I think that with `df`, `-k` option is useless while using `-h` option.

You can see I also delete process about `HOSTNAME` and `USER` because you already gave it to ssh command.

Using your script you can do this :

```
mem_check Variable User Server
{
    ssh $3@$2 a1=$1 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH' >> table
    echo $a1
    echo $HOSTNAME
    echo ${HOME//home/} | tr -d / | sed ':a;N;s/\n/ /g'
    mem=$(df -kh /tmp | grep -vE '^Filesystem|cdrom' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d '%' -f 1 )
    if [ $mem -ge 80 ]; then
        echo -e "$mem% \n<font style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FF0000\">R</font>\n"
    else
        echo -e "$mem% \n<font style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #33cc33\">G</font>\n"
    fi
    ENDSSH
}
```

This will redirect all of the ssh output in your local file.

Comment: I don't think cut % is working, since the test is rejecting the comaparison showing error. "-ge: unary operator expected" also another error n=ub the ssh is "df: unrecognized option `--output=pcent'"

Comment: On a sidenote, the script is working perfectly by using Scp + cat... But I am asking for a soln where the output can be stored directly in the local file.

Comment: I added a solution using your script.

Comment: Yes, Tyvm. I didn't realize I could just redirect the output as a whole just like I was using the code. But I guess that is the inexperience.